# Mismatched rating in Ah and Wh. Why is that?

Tags: batteries, energy, efficiency

My question concerns the apparent mismatch between the Wh rating and the Ah rating often found on batteries.

On one of my batteries the label says:
12V Leisure Battery TR350 TUDOR EXIDE DUAL 80Ah, 350Wh (Effective in 20 h) 510A(EN)

(I)
I thought that **350 Wh** (Effective in 20 h) means that it could deliver **17.5 W for 20 h**. (I also thought this could be interpreted as 20 h with U = 12 V and I = 1.6 A **(E = 12 * 1.46 * 20 Wh = 350 Wh)**).

(II)
I also thought that **80 Ah** for this battery could be interpreted as **I = 4 A, U = 12 V for 20 h**, (4 * 20 = 80 Ah). **Total capacity would then be 960 Wh (4 * 12 * 20 VAh = 960 Wh**).

There is apparently a big mismatch between the two ratings. Why is that? What does rating (I) and rating (II) actually say about the capacity? Is rating (II) suggesting the upper energy limit needed for charging the battery?

I have searched the forum for questions/answers on this topic but none of them cover this very subject. Please correct me if I am wrong. I have also searched the web for explanation for this apparent paradox without finding any clues. Strange. I do hope someone here can help me!

Comment: Perhaps they have borrowed the confusing Ah rating used by USB power bank sellers where the Ah rating refers to Ah if converted to 5V.

Comment: @KristoferA But by that logic, a 12V battery would have more Ah at 5V for the same Wh, not less.

Answer (score 3):

It reads on Exide web page and brochures, that the Wh rating is the watt-hour capacity available from a battery at 20h discharge rate that does not exceed the recommended depth of discharge for given battery.

For AGM batteries the DoD is 75%, so a 100 Ah 12 V battery would be 1200 Wh, but with 75% DoD it is rated only 900 Wh.

So in your case, a 80 Ah 12V battery, with only 36% DoD is not a 960 Wh but a 350 Wh rated battery.